# Cannot load certain URLs in Android Studio WebView but will load others without a problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview, android-manifest

i seem to have an issue with my WebView loading content. i made a simple webview app that is like a google chrome browser. my problem is if i use https://www.google.com/ as the main testing page, during a google search inside of the app links are visible but once you click them i get hit with a Webpage Not Available.

I have Java enabled and Internet access but no matter what i seem to try it does not work the way i would like it to.

with these codes i have right now only Some website urls will load corrently and others wont.

When i am on a webpage and i try to navigate through the site only the Main website page will load, example you go to a website that has a "login" tab, you can view the websites home page correctly but once you click the login tab or any other content tab on that website the screen with either go blank or will give me the webpage not available error.

Here is my Main Activity.java

```js
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView=findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Manifest

```js
  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Example"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@style/splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

    </application>
```

Comment: I would remove the javascript tag as there is no javascript in this question, instead I would add this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-webview

Comment: Welcome !!! use that url in browser and see its working in google browser instead checking in app.

Comment: the url loads perfectly in the external google browser as well as inside the app, for an example. when the app is open and google is displayed, if i search for "ebay" and load the ebay site through the google link it takes me to the ebay landing page, but will not let me load the login page and gives me the Web page not available error. i only seem to be getting this error when i am requesting to Login to a website through webview. But if i do the same thing in the external google browser it allows me to see the login page and successfully login.